# How to install pyaudio in virtual environment for a windows platform?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyaudio

I have installed pyaudio in my main environment and it works completely fine.

But when I try to install pyaudio in virtual environment it is not getting installed. In my virtualenv I am able to install all the other packages except for this one.

I have also done [pip install pipwin] and then [pipwin install pyaudio] , yet it is not working.

I tried to move the pyaudio package from the main environment to the virtual environment to no avail.

I have also tried to install wheel package from unofficial python binaries yet it was unsuccessful.

Please note that I am able to install PyAudio in main environment but unable to install it in my virtual environment.
Can someone please help me out in this?

```
>>> import pyaudio
```

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ateeq\Desktop\fiverr_env\ai\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
import _portaudio as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_portaudio'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're not reporting an error you got during installation using `pip`. On systems that don't have a C compiler set up, `pip install pyaudio` may fail, as it's unable to build `_portaudio` from source. If you do have a C compiler set up, it's possible something didn't go right during the build.

It's probably easiest to grab a built binary from a site like the one maintained by Christoph Golhke [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Note that you'll have to trust them to have created a clean build, without errors or malware. This is why `pip` tries to build it on your machine, so you're only getting source and no pre-built binaries.

I have no affiliation with the site mentioned above, but if you want to save yourself the trouble of figuring out what you need, I did write (the free and open source) library `gohlkegrabber`, which you can use like this:

```
pip install gohlkegrabber
ggrab . pyaudio
```

That'll install a package that allows you to automatically download the appropriate version of the package you need for your system.

However, you can also just forgo the package, and do that manually and then install the downloaded wheel with:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

(of course matching your specific needed version, which may be different from the example)